# Вызов session scope бина из контроллера

Tags: java, spring

Добрый день. Пишу контроллер, который будет через каждое время отправлять по вебсокету на фронтенд данные. Вот этот контроллер:

```
@RestController
@EnableScheduling
@RequestMapping(value = "/task")
public class TaskController {

 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
   public void getTaskForNotification() {
    List l = taskService.getTaskForNotification(sessionUser.getGuid());
    this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userDao.getUserByGuid(sessionUser.getGuid()).getLogin(),"/queue/getTaskForNotification", l);
}

}
```

sessionUser то бин с session scope:

```
@Bean(name = "sessionUser")
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public SystemUser getSystemUser(){
    return new SystemUser();
}
```

Проблема в том, что при попытке обратится к этому бину вылетает ошибка:

```
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.sessionUser': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Всё остальное работает. Подскажите, кто в курсе, как это можно пофиксить.

Comment: Не совсем понял что вы имеете в виду. Можете какой-то пример написать? А то я честно говоря редко сессионными бинами пользуюсь..

Comment: Дело в том, что мой контроллер автономно от всего начинает работать на бекенде. Как же мне тогда весь этот функционал прицепить к конкретной сесии и конкретному сессионному бину?

Comment: Проблема в том, что мой контроллер должен отрабатывать каждое определенное время для своего конкретного юзера. Если я сохраню юзерайди одного юзера, то контроллер будет отрабатывать только для него одного а не для любого залогиненого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

Заинжектил SessionRegistry бин, и уже от туда в рантайме отлавливал какие пользователя сейчас онлайн, а какие нет.

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

List<String> sessionUser = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<Object> allPrincipals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    for(final Object principal : allPrincipals) {
        if(principal instanceof org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) {
            sessionUser.add(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) principal).getUsername());
        }
    }
```

Для этого понадобилось добавить пару строчек в Spring Security конфиг:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Bean
public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}

@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 http.sessionManagement()
.maximumSessions(1)
.sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
}
}
```

А так же в конфигурацию приложения Spring'а, в onStartup метод добавить такую строчку:

```
public class AppInitialiser implements WebApplicationInitializer{

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
    sc.addListener(HttpSessionEventPublisher.class);    
}
}
```

Для этого понадобится зависимость SpringBoot...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Более детально можно посмотреть здесь
[How can I have list of all users logged in (via spring security) my web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271449/how-can-i-have-list-of-all-users-logged-in-via-spring-security-my-web-applicat)